# Firebase Test Phone Number accounts causing internal error

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have an old Firebase Project in which I have some test phone numbers. I'm using Flutter 3.10.6, here's my Flutter doctor:

[image]

I'm using Firebase Auth 4.7.2 but suddenly I started to get this error:

the error is: **An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.-**

I have done this:

1. Replaced the GoogleService-info.plist
2. Removed and created the test account again.
3. Disabled/Enabled the authentication method.
4. Unrestricted the key on google cloud.
5. Downgraded firebase_auth package and tried with 4.4, 4.5, 4.6 and 4.7.

but with no luck.

Has somebody faced this issue as well that could help?

Comment: Hi, did you fix this problem? I have the same now.

Comment: hi @TuanNguyenQuoc, I was using some US numbers as tests number so I ended using test numbers from other countries, but the truth is that I also reached Firebase support and they weren't able to find a solution, so try with different test numbers

Comment: I updated newest version of Flutter and Xcode, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Native code of Firebase in AppDelegate work for me.

[image]